# When is the sequence $\{F_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $m$-adic topology?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, local-rings

[Here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ekesmith/I-adicTopology.pdf) is a question (See question $9$).

It says that we have the ring $K[[x,y]]$ and the ideal $I=\left\langle x,y \right\rangle$, where $K$ is a field.

We to show that the sequence $\{s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n r_ix^iy^{i+2}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the $I$-adic topology.

The same worksheet has the definition of Cauchy sequence.

The terms of the sequence are $$\{s_0=r_0y^2,~s_1=r_0y^2+r_1xy^3,~s_2=r_0y^2+r_1xy^3+r_2x^2y^4,~\cdots\}$$

we have to show that for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n,m \geq d$
$$s_n-s_m \in I^t.$$
For $t=1$, $s_n-s_m \in I$.

For $t=2$, and $d=2$, whenever $n,m \geq 2$ we have $$s_n-s_m \in I^2=\left\langle x,y \right\rangle^2.$$

For $t=n$, we have $s_{n+1}-s_n \in I^{n+2}$.

So the general case is $$s_n-s_m \in I^{n-m+2}.$$

Hence the given sequence is a Cauchy sequence in the $I$-adic topology, I think.

Am I Correct?

In this regard, I have  another question for local ring:

**Question 2:**

Let $O$ be a local ring with unique maximal ideal $m$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of monic irreducible polynomials in $O[x]$ of degree $n$ having roots in $\bar{m}$. Let us define $F_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^nf_n(x)$ and take direct limit $F=\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n$.

When is the sequence $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  a Cauchy sequence in $m$-adic topology ?

Comment: Easier when $O=K[[x,y]]$ because the $m$-adic topology comes from a discrete valuation $v(a)=\sup \{ k, a\in m^k\}$. You get that $\sum_n f_n$ converges iff $v(f_n)\to \infty$ and $\prod_n f_n$ converges to $0$ iff $\sum_n v(f_n)=\infty$ and $\prod_n f_n$ converges to a non-zero value iff $v(f_n-1)\to \infty$.

Comment: @reuns, so the limit power series $F(x)$ exists in $O[x]$ if each $f_n(x)$ has constant term $1$. Is it ? Second, since in our case $f_n(x)$ are monic irreducible, constant coefficient of $f_n$ are prime element, say, $p$. Can we normalize the valuation $v$ suitably so that $F(x)$ exists in $O[x]$ or in $\text{Frac}(O)[x]$ ?

Comment: No.. If $v$ is a discrete valuation on $O$ then $v(\sum_j a_j x^j) = \sup_j v(a_j)$ is a discrete valuation on $O[x]$ and my previous comment applies.

Comment: @reuns, by $v(f_n-1) \to \infty$ do you mean $f_n(x) \to x$  ?

Comment: What do you mean with $f_n(x)\to x$ ?

Comment: @reuns, what do you mean by $v(f_n-1) \to \infty$ ? It means $f_n-1 \to 0$ or $f_n \to 1$. Do you mean this ? If so, what are $f_n$ here ? Because in my questions we are dealing with polynomials $f_n(x) \in O[x]$ and limit of the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)$. So why are you considering $f_n$ only in your comments rather than considering $f_n(x)$? Can you explain please ?

Comment: It means $\lim_{n\to \infty} v(f_n-1)=\infty$ ie. $\lim f_n = 1$ in the $m$-adic topology.

Comment: @reuns, it is not clear to me. What does mean $\lim f_n=1$ ? what is `1` here ? Do you $\lim f_n(x)=1$ or $\lim f_n=identity$ ? Can you please clarify it ?

Comment: The $1$ of your ring.

Comment: For example $\prod_{n\ge 1} (1+t^n)$ converges in $k[[t]]$ while $\prod_{n\ge 1} (1+t/n^2)$ diverges.